# Sort multidimensional array in VBScript

Tags: arrays, sorting, vbscript

How can I "Sort" the multidimensional arrays based on the hole size parameter please?

eg: A simple example would be (Loaded from Text file):

```
> Liv1.HoleSize[0] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[0] = 250 Liv1.HoleY[0] = -55
> Liv1.HoleSize[1] = 14 Liv1.HoleX[1] = 750 Liv1.HoleY[1] = 0
> Liv1.HoleSize[2] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[2] = 900 Liv1.HoleY[2] = -55
```

must then result in :

```
> Liv1.HoleSize[0] = 14 Liv1.HoleX[0] = 750 Liv1.HoleY[0] = 0
> Liv1.HoleSize[1] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[1] = 250 Liv1.HoleY[1] = -55
> Liv1.HoleSize[2] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[2] = 900 Liv1.HoleY[2] = -55
```

Comment: That looks like 3 independent arrays not a multidimensional array, its also not vbscript (it could be valid js) what vbscript data structure is Liv1 & its members?

Comment: Apologies, I am getting the script again and posting more info, thank you

Comment: Hi, you are correct
There are 3 independent arrays
Hole size,HoleX  And HoleY,    
The data types are all "real" numbers 
When read from text file it comes in as string and I convert into real numbers. I am battling to find a method to sort these arrays , unfortunately I only have VBScript to work with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As VBScript has no native sort, you'll have to roll your own sort, or to get a little help from friends.

If your task is to sort your input file (verbatim as given) to an output file in the specified order, `sort.exe` is your friend:

```
  Dim sIn : sIn = "..\data\in00.txt"
  WScript.Echo readAllFromFile(sIn)
  WScript.Echo "-----------"
  Dim sCmd : sCmd = "sort /+19 " & qq(resolvePath(sIn))
  Dim aRet : aRet = goWSLib.Run(sCmd)
  If aRet(0) Then
     ' handle error
  Else
     WScript.Echo aRet(2)
  End If
```

output:

```
================================================================
Liv1.HoleSize[0] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[0] = 250 Liv1.HoleY[0] = -55
Liv1.HoleSize[1] = 14 Liv1.HoleX[1] = 750 Liv1.HoleY[1] = 0
Liv1.HoleSize[2] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[2] = 900 Liv1.HoleY[2] = -55

-----------
Liv1.HoleSize[1] = 14 Liv1.HoleX[1] = 750 Liv1.HoleY[1] = 0
Liv1.HoleSize[0] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[0] = 250 Liv1.HoleY[0] = -55
Liv1.HoleSize[2] = 22 Liv1.HoleX[2] = 900 Liv1.HoleY[2] = -55

================================================================
```

If something like that solves your problem, just say so, and we can talk the support code in the library functions.

If, however, you have (to) parse(d) the input file into a two-dimensional array, the best friend you can get is a disconnectes ADODB recordset:

```
  Dim aData : aData = Split(Join(Array( _
          "22 250 -55" _
        , "14 750 0"   _
        , "22 900 -55" _
        , "11 222 333" _
  )))
  Dim afData(3, 2)
  Dim nRows : nRows = UBound(afData, 1)
  Dim nCols : nCols = UBound(afData, 2)
  Dim i, r, c
  For i = 0 TO UBound(aData)
      r = i \   nRows
      c = i Mod (nCols + 1)
      afData(r, c) = aData(i)
'      WScript.Echo i, r, c, aData(i)
  Next
  For r = 0 To nRows
      For c = 0 To nCols
          WScript.StdOut.Write vbTab & afData(r, c)
      Next
      WScript.Echo
  Next
  WScript.Echo "-----------------"
  Dim oRS : Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  For c = 0 To nCols
      oRS.Fields.Append "Fld" & c, adInteger
  Next
  oRS.Open
  For r = 0 To nRows
      oRS.AddNew
      For c = 0 To nCols
          oRS.Fields(c).value = afData(r, c)
      Next
      oRS.UpDate
  Next
  oRS.Sort = "Fld0"
  WScript.Echo oRS.GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo "-----------------"
  oRS.Sort = "Fld2"
  WScript.Echo oRS.GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
========================================
        22      250     -55
        14      750     0
        22      900     -55
        11      222     333
-----------------
11      222     333
14      750     0
22      250     -55
22      900     -55

-----------------
22      250     -55
22      900     -55
14      750     0
11      222     333

========================================
```

Again: if that looks promising, we can discuss how to adapt/streamline this proof of concept code to your needs.

Comment: I like disconnected recordsets a lot. So versatile.

Comment: hi, thank you so much, this looks amazing, I will sit tonight with a test file and reply , thank you!

Comment: hi, this is brilliant thanks, for the first time there are signs of hope, the last example you showed looks great. Can I ask please, I copied the code of the last block into c:\MyFile.vbs, and then in cmd prompt ran cscript MyFile.vbs, and got the error "C:\MyFile.vbs(26,7) ADODB.Fields: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another". I s there perhaps something wrong in the way I am executing it please? I tried to debug my side by replacing the "adInteger" with the digit "1" but still get the same error, thank you!

Comment: @PeterPitLock adInteger=3: adClipString=2 Have a look for adovbs.inc