# Sort based on the first column in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I got requirement to get the top CPU utilizing processes in machines in the infrastructure.
I was able to achieve this by listing down all the processes with thier CPU utilization percentage along with some more details as given below

```
CPU% PID  USERNAME        PROCESSNAME
21%  484  SYSTEM          svchost.exe
0%   1116 SYSTEM          svchost.exe
0%   1260 SYSTEM          snac64.exe
0%   1844 NETWORK         SERVICE CdfSvc.exe
0%   1900 SYSTEM          cdfre.exe
0%   1956 LOCAL           SERVICE CAudioService.exe
0%   2336 LOCAL           SERVICE svchost.exe
2%   2376 LOCAL           SERVICE pidSvc.exe
0%   2528 LOCAL           SERVICE svchost.exe
0%   2560 SYSTEM          ccSvcHst.exe
0%   2816 SYSTEM          sftvsa.exe
0%   2952 SYSTEM          Shopping.exe
0%   3240 NETWORK SERVICE WorksAgent.exe
0%   3344 LOCAL SERVICE   encsvc.exe
0%   3388 LOCAL SERVICE   USB.exe
3%   3564 NETWORK SERVICE WmvSE.exe
```

And I have put this output in a file such that this file can be sorted based on the first column i.e CPU%

Is there a built in function for sorting? Or else any other way to achieve this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566077/603855 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12289477/603855 (follow the links).

Comment: [Another option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16289700/1630171).